# Anagrams, synonyms and antonym

Tags: word, word-property

You may have seen word puzzles where two words are given and the puzzle asks you to transfer one letter from one of the words to the other creating two words that are synonyms.

For example:  Smarts and Harp. Move “s” over then Smart = Sharp. Fairly easy.

Here is a challenging version

Given 3 words

Transfer exactly one letter from each word to another creating 3 new words.
Each word must transfer exactly 1 letter and also receive exactly 1 letter.

So at the end each word gives up one letter to one of the other 2 words and also receives 1 letter. So the number of letters in those words do not change.

The **anagrams** of the 3 new words must be such that 2 words are synonyms and the remaining word is the antonym of the 2 words. Example (Right, Correct, Wrong).

> The 3 starting words
>
> Pest
>
> Bingo
>
> Deists

The final words are in the Merriam Webster dictionary

Comment: Since there are 3 words, can we take one letter from one word and place the same letter on the other 2 words, or only on one of those 2 words?

Comment: You can transfer any one letter to one other word. You can transfer same letter to the third word if you want.

Comment: Yes. It says anagram of the 3 new words.

Comment: So after a letter transfer the new word is dog, you then can anagram it to say god

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Stop, begin, desist.
>  Moved the e, o, and e.
>  Actually I misread the question, forgot the first part. Could be Post, binge, and um now I'm stuck. Unless deists is considered a different word from deists due to the e moving....

Comment: I think your first example is okay actually (follows the rules).

Answer (score 2):

Letter Swaps

> "pest" gives an "e" to deists."

> What is now "deistse" gives an "e" to "bingo."

> What is now "bingoe" gives an "o" to what is now "pst."

> In the end, we have "post," "deists," and "binge."

Therefore,

> Anagram of "post" is "stop." Anagram of "deists" is "desist." Anagram of "binge" is "begin." "Stop" and "desist" are synonyms, while "begin" is an antonym.